# How to convert SQL Database to Mongodb?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database-schema, nosql

I am having a bit of trouble with what the best schema would be in mongo for some golf data that I have.

```
Tables:
ClubManufacturer (id, name, descr) -- ex: 1, Titleist
ClubType (id, name) -- ex: 1, Driver
Club (id, id_clubType, id_clubManufacturer, name, url) -- ex: 1, 1, 1, 913D2, link
```

Should I just store each club manufacturer as a document with club (and type) as properties of the document? I am at a loss because I'll be needing to access the data such that I need to show, all Drivers, or, all clubs by manufacturer.

I am also new to mongodb so any insight is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what properties does each manufacturer have?  it looks like it's just "name" so then why normalize?  Just store the name in the club collection and store club type as a field there as well...

Comment: actually there is, manufacturer has a "description", I have updated the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your Manufacturer and Type tables are actually much larger than what you listed here, it seems simple to just have each document in Club collection look something like:

```
{ _id: 1,
  manufacturer: 'Titleist',
  type: 'Driver',
  name: '913D2',
  url: 'http://blah.blah.blah/'
}
```

Now you can index manufacturer and type fields to support fast queries by either of the attributes.

Comment: actually there is, manufacturer has a "description", I have updated the OP.

Comment: you can keep that in a separate collection which has all manufacturers - do you actually need to ever search clubs by description of manufacturer?

Comment: no, searches are pretty generic, by club, by club type, and by manufacturer. the description is just for the manufacturer search info page.

Comment: I think that's the best structure in this case, the queries you gave as examples would be very simple:
`db.clubs.find({"type": "Driver"})`
`db.clubs.find({"manufacturer": "Titleist"})`

Answer (score 1):

If your manufacturers have large descriptions then you might want to keep them separate to reduce the redundancy. As an extension of Asya Kamsky's answer:

```
Manufacturer Collection:
{
   _id: "Manufacturer Name",
  description: "Long ... Description"
}

Club Collection:
{
  _id: Auto_Generated_Hash,
  manufacturer: "Name/ID",
  type: "Driver",
  name: "Club Name",
  url: "http://www.url.com/"
}
```

I used the manufacturer's name as the _id so that if you don't need the description you still know what the manufacturer is without doing a "join".